# Background image not changing with setInterval

Tags: javascript

I try to change background image using `setInterval`. Only the image changes just once. I have tried to change width value instead and it works.

```js
var hero = document.getElementById('hero')
console.log(hero)

var heroBg = hero.style.backgroundImage;
console.log(heroBg)

function change() {
  console.log('this is showing in the console')

  if (hero.style.background === 'url(./images/image2.jpg)') {
    console.log('this is not showing in the console')
    hero.style.background = 'url(./images/image1.jpg)'
    console.log('testcondition1')
  } else {
    console.log('this is showing in the console')
    hero.style.background = 'url(./images/image2.jpg)'
  }
}

setInterval(change, 3000);
```

EDIT : this works

```
    if(hero.style.backgroundImage == 'url("./images/image2.jpg")'){
        console.log('test1')
        hero.style.backgroundImage = 'url("./images/image1.jpg")'
        console.log('testcondition1')
    }else{
        console.log('test2')
        hero.style.backgroundImage='url("./images/image2.jpg")'
    }
```

I have tried to use double quotes inside the parenthesis and this works. The double quotes outside and single quote inside does not.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting `hero.style.backgroundImage`?

Comment: Try `console.log(hero.style.background);` and you will see the problem.

Comment: In Firefox your conditions will never be true. `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("./images/image2.jpg") repeat scroll 0% 0%` is what comes back.

Comment: I tried backgroundImage , that was my first attempt

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing the background CSS property that may be inconsistent across browsers, you may want to use a boolean flag instead.

```
let flag = true;
function change() {
  console.log('this is showing in the console')
  if (flag) {
    console.log('this is not showing in the console')
    hero.style.background = 'url(./images/image1.jpg)'
    console.log('testcondition1')
  } else {
    console.log('this is showing in the console')
    hero.style.background = 'url(./images/image2.jpg)'
  }
  flag = !flag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would utilize data attributes to store the state of the hero and just flip between the states.

You can use the value of `currentState` inside of `change`, to determine what to do.

Do not attempt to run style information through a conditional, because you are going to have a bad time.

```js
const maxStates = 2
const hero = document.getElementById('hero')

function change() {
  let currentState = parseInt(hero.dataset.state || 0, 10)
  currentState = (currentState + 1) % maxStates
  hero.dataset.state = currentState
}

setInterval(change, 2000); // Update every 2 seconds.
```

```css
#hero {
  width: 200px;
  height: 287px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/287');
}

#hero[data-state="1"] {
  background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/200/286');
}
```

```html
<div id="hero"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

in if change **background** to **backgroundImage**

```
hero.style.background
```

Comment: The ifs are never entered. This sadly doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: try console.log(hero.style.background) to show what return before if

Comment: console.log(heroBg, "test") returns(i see "test") but heroBg is empty